# How can I use Throws with multiple if/else conditions?

Tags: java, exception

I have a method using throws, inside is two if/else statements, the if statement tests a condition and then throws an exception if it fails, the problem is of course is that if the first if/else block fails my second never gets executed, is there an alternative way to approach this problem?

**EDIT (Further Information)**

My code is checking whether a person object has the correct first name Test 1, or the correct surname Test 2, if not throw exception A or B, code further on then adds the person into a group if they pass both conditions

```
  Method throws Exception A, Exception B
{
    //Test First name 
    if(Test1)
    {
      If persons firstname is correct, Test1 is true
    }
    else
    {
      throw new Exception A
    }

    //Test Surname
    if(Test2)
    {
      If persons surname is correct, Test2 is true
    }
    else
    {
      throw new Exception B
    }

   //If everything is fine, add the person to a list.
   if (Test1 & Test2)
   {
     Add Person to a list
   }
}
```

Comment: Why would you want your program to continue when it throws an exception?

Comment: the whole purpose of throwing exceptions is to stop execution of current method and signal the caller that a problem has occurred. if you need the code to continue running, then you dont really need an exception

Comment: I think this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).  You are using exceptions for flow control, and that is a seriously bad antipattern.  You likely don't want to use exceptions at all but you haven't given us enough information to know.

Comment: My crystall ball tells me that you want to report all errors as part of input validation.

Comment: It is checking whether a person object has the correct first name Test 1, or the correct surname Test 2, if not throw exception A or B, code further on then adds the person into a group if they pass both conditions.

Comment: @Ninja2k Are you still here?

Comment: Hi @Ninja2k, We can make both the statements Test1 and Test2 to get validated but imagine a case where both Test1 and test2 fails, which exception are you going to throw? How can you know that both the statements failed just by throwing either exception A or Exception B??

Answer (score 1):

Based upon your description, I am thinking that you could change to

```
if(Test1)
{
    if(!Test2)
    {
       throw new Exception B
    }
    // Do some work here
}
else
{
  throw new Exception A
}
```

Another way to consider is by creating methods

```
bool test1 = correctFirstName (fname);
bool test2 = correctLastName (lname);

if (test1 && test2) 
{
    // do some stuff
}
else {
    if (!test1) // throw ExceptionA
    else // throw ExceptionB
}
```

Comment: Afraid that didn't work, the result was the same, nice try though!

Comment: I am afraid you explanation is not very clear, **but** I have edited amy answer.  Is that what you are wanting?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. I would of course recommend not using generic Exception, but I would also not use two different types of exceptions as your original code implied.

```
  Method throws Exception A, Exception B
{
    String errMsg = "";

    //Test First name 
    if(Test1)
    {
      If persons firstname is correct, Test1 is true
    }
    else
    {
      errMsg = "Invalid first name";
    }

    //Test Surname
    if(Test2)
    {
      If persons surname is correct, Test2 is true
    }
    else
    {
      errMsg = "Invalid surname";
    }

   //If everything is fine, add the person to a list.
   if (errMsg.equals(""));
   {
     Add Person to a list
   }
   else
   {
      throw new Exception(errMsg);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears the task is not possible, the instructions given to me did not state that in order to trigger one Exception or the other I had to comment out code.